# Use GroovyShell to run scripts from Java code

Tags: java, groovy

I write project, where I work with Groovy and Java.
I have this Groovy script in my project:

```
int sum(def a, def b) {
return (int)a + (int)b;
}
```

And in my Main Java class I write this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int answer = 0;
    String[] arguments = new String[]{"1", "2"};
    GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell();
    try {
        answer = (int) shell.run(new File("src/Summary.groovy"), arguments);
        System.out.print(answer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I have `NullPointerException` in this line: `answer = (int) shell.run(new File("src/Summary.groovy"), arguments);`
So, what I want? I want run Main class and call groovy script, which contain function of sum a + b and return this value to Java code.
How can I do it correct?
UPD:
Full stackTrace from Main class:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Main.main(Main.java:12)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

UPD2:
Incorrect output:
`a:1 b:2 answer: 33`
I use this script:

```
def sum (int a, int b) {
print("a:" + a + " b:" + b + "\n")
return a + b
}
return sum (args[0].toInteger(), args[1].toInteger())
```

And code from Main class correct call it, but answer incorrect

Comment: It would be much easier if you put the full stack trace... It will enable us to find out which part was `null` in the line...

Comment: @Codebender I put stack trace from Main class, which start my project

Comment: @Giymose, so now investigate line no 140.

Comment: Your groovy script appears to be casting Strings to int.  This isn't the problem you're seeing now, but I believe it will be your next problem on the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call something in your script - not just provide a function. So your script could look like:

```
int sum(def a, def b) {
   return ((int)a) + ((int)b)
}
return sum (args[0], args[1])
```

Still casting a String to an int looks really weird - maybe you wanted to parse the strings to ints or something (e.g. `"1".toInteger()` or `a.toInteger()` as in your case).

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I do it, but result isn't correct.
I see:
a:1 b:2
answer: 33.
see code in top

Comment: It works fine on my box - printing out "3". Are you sure you don't print the result out twice? `
a:1 b:2
3
Process finished with exit code 0`